# QGIS Multiple CASE WHEN/THEN Statements for Expression Based Labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

I am trying to label a single point with multiple labels, based on the attributes for that point.  For example, if one of the attributes is equal to 1, I want to label it with a specific text string; and if another attribute is equal to 0, I want to label it with a different text string, etc.  In addition, I want to use other attribute information to control the placement of the labels around the point, as well as their color.

Can multiple CASE WHEN/THEN expressions be stacked, to achieve the desired result?  I have tried to include multiple WHEN/THEN statements inside my CASE expression, looking like this:

```
CASE
WHEN attribute1 = 1 THEN 'Apple'
WHEN attribute2 = 0 THEN 'Grape'
WHEN attribute3 >= 0 THEN 'Pear'
END
```

This returns the desired label for `attribute1`, but ignores the labels for the other two attributes.  I believe this is because a CASE statement can only refer to a single variable/attribute at a time?  If that is true, is there another conditional expression type I can use to achieve what I want?  I'm trying to avoid having to add the point layer multiple times to my project, in order to label based on different attributes.

Comment: I am quite new of QGIS and so I'm sorry if I am asking a question already posted. Anyway, my question is: if I want to change just some values with a conditional statement while maintain the other ones as they are, what should I write? In Excel I would write: IF(cell1=x;"y";"") But in QGIS?: CASE WHEN "attribute 1"='x' THEN 'y'ELSE [????]
Thank you so much
Federica

Comment: You could use rule-based labelling with one rule for each of your case. It would then make it easy to display it how and where you want.

Answer (score 11):

The `CASE` statement *can* include multiple attributes in multiple conditions (or even in the same condition: `WHEN attribute1 = 1 AND attribute2 = 0 THEN…` is legal). But `CASE` evaluates the conditions in order and stops evaluating after it reaches the first condition that is satisfied. So, for your example, if `attribute1 = 1` evaluates to `TRUE`, the rest of the conditions won't be evaluated.

You could do something like:

```
CASE WHEN attribute1 = 1 THEN 'Apple|' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN attribute2 = 0 THEN 'Grape|' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN attribute3 >= 0 THEN 'Pear|' ELSE '' END
```

and then use QGIS settings to introduce line breaks on the pipe (`'|'`) character, which will at least get each word on its own line. (There is an extra pipe at the end which may have to be handled.) Note that the `ELSE ''` is necessary. Otherwise, if one of the conditions doesn't evaluate to `TRUE`, the `CASE` will return `NULL`, and `NULL` concatenated with any text will return `NULL`.

But to get to your larger question, I don't think you can have "Apple", "Grape", etc. appear in different positions around the feature, different colors, etc., even using data-defined properties. I think to achieve what you want you will have to create label-only duplicates of your layer, and have one layer print labels for `attribute1` in the desired position and color, 
another layer print labels for `attribute2` in the desired position and color, etc.

Comment: Not sure why your expression doesn't work for me, but I think this also works as an alternative: `CASE WHEN  "attribute1"  = 1 THEN 'Apple|' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN  "attribute2 " =  0 THEN 'Grape|' ELSE '' END +...`

Comment: @Joseph The information/ideas from both of you are certainly helpful.  I was able to get the text of the different attributes to draw, using a '|' as a line break character, and stacking the CASE statements using a + symbol.  However, as has been suggested, it looks like the best way for me to get the results I want (regarding color and placement) is to draw label-only duplicates of the layer.

Comment: Sorry, `RTRIM()` is a Postgres function not available in QGIS expression editor. QGIS does offer `trim()`, but this only removes whitespace, not specified characters like `'|'`. I've updated answer to remove this function. I was using it to strip the final pipe from the string. As pipe is replaced by newline, it may not make a difference, i.e. it won't be visible, but it might also cause label position to shift.

Comment: Note that while `+` seems to work for string concatenation, `||` is standard SQL. In fact, if you check the buttons available in the expression editor, the tooltip for `+` is "Addition operator" while the tooltip for `||` is "String Concatenation".

Comment: @LeeHachadoorian - Thank you for the info, that's good to know!

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want to accomplish is rather a usecase for `CASE WHEN...` statements, but for 'rule based labels' (as suggested in one of the above comments):

[image]

For example, you may define a rule called 'Grape' and the expression for this rule would be `"attribute1" = 0`. For each rule you can set up each parameter (font color, size, placement, ...) separately. For the Grapes for example I've set this up as follows:

Filter expression, text color, label:
[image]

Placement (here Bottom-left, or S-W):
[image]

Additionally I've enabled `Show all labels for this layer`: 
[image]

The result looks like shown below (note the attribute Table):
[image]