# Update existing field using CASE -statement

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, conditional

When I run this statement in qgis fieldcalc it returns correct reults only from the first line ('Skog') and the rest gets NULL-values.

Any ideas what might be wrong here? Is it not pocssible to run CASE-statement inlcuding several lines? It seems to work when I run it with the three middle rows excluded.

```
CASE  
when "KATEGORI"  LIKE '%skog' then 'Skog'  
when "KATEGORI"  LIKE '%vatten%' then 'Vattenomrade'  
when "KATEGORI"  LIKE '%Annan%' then 'Oppen mark'  
when "KATEGORI"  LIKE '%ker%' then 'Oppen mark'  
Else 'Bebyggd och Hardgjord mark'  
END
```

Comment: Your syntax looks fine. Could you add your attribute table (or part of it) to your question? Also, [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/162298/64955) might help.

Comment: Thanks for helpful link! However, It all worked out just by changning som letters to upper case.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
CASE KATEGORI 
   WHEN '%skog' THEN 'Skog'  
   WHEN '%vatten%' THEN 'Vattenomrade'  
   WHEN '%Annan%' THEN 'Oppen mark'  
   WHEN '%ker%' THEN 'Oppen mark'  
   ELSE 'Bebyggd och Hardgjord mark' 
END
```

Comment: Thanks!  My first syntax was correct after all, except for some mistakes using lower case....