# QGIS multiple CASE WHEN doesn't work in rule-based labelling

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have the rule-based labelling provided for my labels, inside which I want to make other distinctions. Unfortunately, the multiple CASE WHEN seem to be not valid, as I get an error:

**Parser Errors:
syntax error, unexpected STRING
syntax error, unexpected END, expecting $end**

My code looks like this so far:

```
CASE WHEN
"rotate_angle" = 90 THEN
'10,0'
ELSE 
"rotate_angle" = 270 AND "Plan" = E
'8,10'
END
```

and I believe the situation is similar to this query:

[QGIS Multiple CASE WHEN/THEN Statements for Expression Based Labels](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162297/qgis-multiple-case-when-then-statements-for-expression-based-labels)

where the rule-based styling was proposed. In my case it has been already applied, but I need a step further - a few rules inside of the given rule. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Please provide example data. I suppose the `"rotate_angle" = 270` is superfluous, but can't confirm w/o having a look at the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have `ELSE` with a condition. `ELSE` is used for catch *all others values*, so it's a syntax error.

And `E` seems to be a literal value --> missing quote (`'E'`)

```
CASE 
  WHEN "rotate_angle" = 90 THEN '10,0'
  WHEN "rotate_angle" = 270 AND "Plan" = 'E' THEN '8,10'
END
```

or just

```
CASE 
  WHEN "rotate_angle" = 90 THEN '10,0'
  ELSE '8,10'
END
```